# Can we encourage people to keep previous golf versions?

Tags: discussion

I love seeing that someone started at 100 characters and got it down to 26, but I would love to see each version or have record of what those optimizations were.

Am I just missing it? Leave that stuff in people!

Comment: You can view the edit history of any answer to see the previous versions.

Comment: There *is* a record in the edit history. At the bottom of answers, there is sometimes a link that says something like "edited <date>", which you can click and see the revision history. All the previous versions will be in there.

Comment: Ah, ha. I'm blind. Thanks guys! Now I feel dumb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If they were already in your answer, please don't. Challenges here sometimes get a ton of answers, and we already encourage detailed explanations which can make the answers quite long. If all of the previous versions were kept in the answer, that would require a lot of screen real estate and scrolling.

**But** (as Mego said) the previous versions aren't lost. You can view the edit history of any answer by clicking the "edit [date] at [time]" link at the bottom of the answer. Then you can browse all the previous versions. People usually leave their previous *scores* in the answer using strikethrough markup:

```
## Ruby, <s>61</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes
```

The main purpose of that is to tell people that there *were* previous versions which can be found in the edit history, so if you see that you can go check them out. One exception to that might be if you've already golfed it quite a lot before first posting the answer. In that case, showing some interesting earlier versions might be nice.

You're right though, it can be quite interesting to follow someone else's golfing process. This is actually one of the reasons why I prefer posting a working answer early, before I'm 100% done golfing it, so that there's a record of the actual golfing process. There's two answers of mine on the quine challenge that show the two extremes: I posted my [Retina quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67428/8478) straight at 20 bytes after a golfing session that started at 90 bytes. I even included those old versions straight in the answer there, because I thought they were interesting, and there would otherwise have been no record of them. The opposite is my [Prelude quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47112/8478) which I first posted at ~5000 bytes and golfed down through a *lot* of version down to 214 bytes. Those versions can all be found in the edit history.